# Broadcom 4311 wifi ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless

I just installed ubuntu 13.10 on my dell vostro 1000 laptop. It has the broadcom 4311 wireless.

It doesn't work, ubuntu software centre shows I have the bcmwl kernel source drivers and the Linux firmware drivers already on.  ( I noticed other questions have said the solution is to remove the former and install the latter.)

However I have no way of getting an Ethernet connection, is it not possible to do it from the USB install?

If not, how will I download the packages I need from a friends laptop tomorrow?

Comment: Why is your ethernet unavailable? It may be blacklisted. Please edit your question to add details of your devices from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep -e 0280 -e 0200

Comment: My Ethernet isn't unavailable, but I have no physical access to am Ethernet connection is what I meant. So if it's not possible to get it working without the Internet I'm wondering how I go about acquiring the Linux-firmware-nonfree package from a friends Mac and installing them on ubuntu via USB? I have the broadcom 4311 wireless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On another computer, download this package: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/l/linux-firmware-nonfree/linux-firmware-nonfree_1.14ubuntu1_all.deb Transfer it with a USB drive or similar to the Ubuntu computer. Drag and drop it to the desktop. Right-click it and select 'Open with Ubuntu Software Center.' After it completes, reboot and your wireless should be working.